# Problema en tratamiento de lista en Python

Tags: python, consola

Programa que suma las filas y columnas de una determinada matriz y retorna los pares de esa suma en forma de una nueva tupla

```
import funcion

lista1 = [1, 2, 3]
lista2 = [10, 9, 8]
resultado_final_obtenido = funcion.manejo_lista(lista1, lista2)
print(resultado_final_obtenido)

def manejo_lista(lista1, lista2):
    lista_vacia = []
    for i in lista1:
        concatenacion = lista1

        for j in lista2:
            union = lista2


            result = [(concatenacion, union)]


    return result
```

OUTPUT

```
[(0, 1, 2), (10, 9, 8)]
```

Comment: Si la respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, por favor, márcala cómo solución! Así mismo, no edites la pregunta quitándola, pues puede ser útil para futuros usuarios al ser una buena pregunta! :)

Comment: Para marcarla como solución como te dice M.K tienes que pulsar el tick verde bajo la puntuación de la respuesta que quieras aceptar como buena.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que te estás haciendo un lío con el tema de los bucles y los elementos de la lista.

Como estás iniciandote, te recomiendo lo siguiente: usar las posiciones de listas en vez de los elementos. **WARNING:** Aquí suponemos que las listas son del mismo tamaño!!!

Así pues tu nueva función quedaría así:

```
def manejo_lista(lista1, lista2):
    lista_tuplas = []
    for i in range(len(lista1)):
        lista_tuplas.append((lista1[i],lista2[i]))

    return lista_tuplas
```

No solo es mucho más eficiente en cuanto a complejidad temporal ya que solo tenemos un bucle que recorre la longitud de la lista `n`, si no que es bastante sencillo de entender:

Hacemos `append` en `lista_tuplas`del elemento `i`de la primera lista con el elemento `i` de la segunda lista.

Resultado:

```
[(1, 10), (2, 9), (3, 8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

En python 3

```
In: list(zip(lista1, lista2))
Out: [(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 8)]
```

Otra forma es usar list comprehension

```
In: [(lista1[i], lista2[i]) for i in range(0,len(lista1))]
Out: [(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 8)]
```

Comment: Respuesta editada

Answer (score 1):

El problema de tu código es que por cada iteración de una lista iteras la otra lista completa.

Esto es más sencillo de resolver con una simple iteración.

```
def manejo_lista(lista1, lista2):
  result = []
  for i in range(len(lista1)):
    result.append((lista1[i], lista2[i]))

  return result
```

La única condición seria que `lista1` y `lista2`tengan el mismo tamaño.

Comment: El problema seria cuando la `lista1` sea más grande que la `lista2` y se trataria de acceder un indice no existente en la `lista2` lanzando un error.